# ASP Web API - Kendo Grid and Model State

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo Grid and ModelState.IsValid condition on my Web API post method. When I create a new record on the grid (in fact I'm using the popup option of the grid to create a new record), it's sending the Id of my class as null, then when it comes to my controller the ModelState is always invalid because it expects the Id of my class to be 0. I solved it by changing the value of the Id on the parameterMap of the datasource when the operation is 'create' (see code below), but I really don't know if it's the best solution as it seems to me like a poor way. Is there another option to solve this issue? Thanks.

View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "PUT"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/api/products/" + data.id;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "DELETE"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/api/products",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                // THIS IS MY FIX FOR NOW
                if (operation === "create") {
                    options.id = 0;
                }
                return kendo.stringify(options);
            },
            type: "json"
        },
        batch: false,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    name: { validation: { required: true } },
                    description: { validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "description", title: "Description" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" 
        }],
        editable: "popup"
    });
});
```

Controller (I put only the post method as it was the one that got the issue):

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    _productRepository.CreateProduct(product);
    _productRepository.SaveProduct();

    return Ok(product);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
    public void CreateProduct(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(product);
    }

    public void SaveProduct()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show View (*the rest of the code)* and Product Model?

Comment: I updated the question with full code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that ***id*** field is `nullable: true`.

Could you remove it and add `type: "number"`?

```
fields: {
   id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
   name: { validation: { required: true } },
   description: { validation: { required: true } }
}
```